# How to extract image urls using jsoup

Tags: java, jsoup

I want to fetch content from a website, such as `title` and `src` attributes of the images. Can any one help me out to achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example of reading all image `src` and `title` attributes:

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.golem.de/").get();
            Elements imageElements = doc.getElementsByTag("img");
            for (Element element : imageElements) {
                System.out.println("src: "+element.attr("src"));
                System.out.println("title: "+element.attr("title"));
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much flavio.donze it helped me a lot